# dual composition of binary relations

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

I'm not sure if this is of any interest at all, but I spent some time looking at it a couple of years ago so I'd like to ask for input on this.

Given two binary relations $\rho,\,\sigma$ on a set $X,$ we can compose them by the standard definition:

$$\rho\circ\sigma=\{(a,b)\in X\times X\,|\,(\exists\,c\in X)((a,c)\in\rho\wedge(c,b)\in\sigma)\}.$$

This can be seen as a composition of endomorphisms of the "semi vector space" (or vector semispace, or whatever it's called) $\Bbb B^n,$ where $n=|X|$ and $\Bbb B$ is the semifield $(\{0,1\},\vee,\wedge).$ This is seen by identifying subsets of $X$ with binary vectors by their characteristic function and considering the action of binary relations on $2^X$ by images. In particular, this shows that this composition distributes over the union operation.

Now we can De Morgan-flip the definition and take

$$\rho\star\sigma=\{(a,b)\in X\times X\,|\,(\forall\,c\in X)((a,c)\in\rho\vee(c,b)\in\sigma)\}.$$

I've never seen this operation defined anywhere. $2^{X\times X}$ with $\star$ is isomorphic to $2^{X\times X}$ with $\circ$ by the complement function. Similarly, it can be viewed as the space of endomorphisms of $\tilde{\Bbb B}^n,$ where $\tilde{\Bbb B}$ is the semifield $(\{0,1\},\wedge,\vee)$ (where the additive operation is written first). Consequently, $\star$ distributes over intersection.

Is there any law connecting $\circ$ and $\star$? Distributive laws do not work. I've been trying to see if $\rho\circ(\sigma\star\tau)\subseteq(\rho\circ\sigma)\star(\rho\circ\tau),$ but no. It does seem that it holds for almost all triples $\rho,\sigma,\tau$ (by computer calculations up to n=20) but there are exceptions.

Another question is if $\star$ has ever been defined and named.

Comment: You might consider looking at join and meet of binary relations.  Tarski and his school considered relation algebras and their connections to logic.  You might start with students of algebraic logic and follow the suggestions they may have.